# Excel loop macro ending early and needing to keep files open to copy several loops(different files)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a bit of a problem with this VBA code

```
Sub upONGOING_Train1()
ScreenUpdating = False
'set variables
Dim rFndCell As Range
Dim strData As String
Dim stFnd As String
Dim fCol As Integer
Dim oCol As Integer
Dim SH As Worksheet
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim strFName As String
Dim objCell As Object

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trains")
For Each objCell In WS.Range("L3:L100")
    oCol = objCell.Column
     strFName = WS.Cells(, oCol).Offset(objCell.Row - 1, 0)
     On Error GoTo BLANK: 'skip macro if no train
     Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFName 'open ongoing report
     Set SH = Worksheets("Trains") 'set sheet
     stFnd = WS.Cells(, oCol).Offset(objCell.Row - 1, 2).Value 'set connote
    With SH
        Set rFndCell = .Range("C3:C1100").Find(stFnd, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rFndCell Is Nothing Then
            fCol = rFndCell.Column
            WS.Cells(, oCol).Offset(objCell.Row - 1, 3).Resize(1, 6).Copy
            SH.Cells(, fCol).Offset(rFndCell.Row - 1, 10).Resize(1, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste values in ongoing report if connote found
            ActiveWorkbook.Save 'save ongoing report
            ActiveWorkbook.Close 'close ongoing report
        Else 'Can't find the item
        End If
    End With
BLANK:
    Next objCell
ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What I want it to do is - for every row in L3:L100

- Open file listed in column "L" (if there or skip line to next one) and go to sheet
- Match value from original sheet column "N" to "C3:C1100" in newly opened sheet
- Copy columns "O:T" and paste relative to the matching value in the opened sheet(M:R) and save

However when I leave a gap of 2 rows it gives me the error for file not found instead of proceeding to the next loop like it does when there is only 1 row missing.

Seems i can't post images yet.

Also if anyone can point me in a good direction on how to open the sheet in the cell reference only if it is not already open it will usually only have 2 files to use (max of 4 at end of quarter).
Its just too much trouble to click OK on all the windows that pop up when you try to reopen an already open workbook.

If its any help to get your head around it.
I have 2 separate reports for 2 clients(new each quarter so max of 4 sheets at a time) that will already have the names to be searched (2 sheets in each book).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks heaps

Thanks to those who have put forth suggestions and code.
I'll them out tomorrow and failing that I've just come up with another idea that to re-purpose some other code I have but didn't realize would help.
The code basically copies what I need to a blank tab and deletes rows with a given value - with some formulas to help sort this would give me a block of rows with no breaks all going to the same destination file.
Thus allowing me to run the (a bit more streamlined *Thanks everyone*) loop over the remaining rows.

Comment: Remove `On Error GoTo` and add `Option Explicit` on top of your code,  to leave the file open remove `ActiveWorkbook.Close` -

Comment: Can you also share image of both worksheet

Comment: thanks for the reply I've tried what you have suggested and removing On Error GoTo makes it stop as soon as there is a single row without a value.  If I stop closing the book it keeps popping up with a message saying the file is open and reopening will cause... and this can happen up to 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `On Error GoTo BLANK`
>
> `Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFName`

Change the above into this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFName
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Goto Blank
```

As to hpw keep the workbook open, you can leave it open (no `.close`) but then when you want to open it check first if it is open (i.e. using `Workbooks("name")`), with some error handling using the same mechanism as above, if error exists then the wb is not already open, you open it.

Finally, avoid counting on the `Active` stuff, such as the ActiveWorkbook`. Instead, make an explicit reference to you wb, i.e.:

```
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFName)
 Set SH = wb.Worksheets("Trains")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I'll give it a try in the morning

Comment: thanks that solved the problem as asked very well - I've had to go down a different path for the sake of other users but mostly the same

Answer (score 0):

to consider only not blank cells you can use [SpecialCells()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) method of `Range` object and leave off any `On Error GoTo` statements, that should be used in very a few limited cases (one of which we'll see in a second)

furthermore you're using some uselessly long winded 'loops' to reference your relevant cells, for instance:

```
WS.Cells(, oCol).Offset(objCell.Row - 1, 0)
```

is equivalent to `objCell` itself!

and there are some more examples of that kind

finally, let's come to the workbooks open/close issue

you could:

- use a `Dictionary` object to store the name of all opened workbooks so as to leave then open throughout your macro and close them all by the end of it
- adopt a helper function that tries to set the wanted sheet (i.e. "Trains") in the wanted workbook (i.e. the one whose name is the current `objCell` value) and return False if not successful

all what above in this refactoring of your code:

```
Sub upONGOING_Train1bis()
    Dim rFndCell As Range
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim objCell As Range
    Dim shtDict As New Scripting.Dictionary '<--| this is the dictionary that will store every opened workbook name as its 'keys'
    Dim key As Variant
'    Dim dec As String '<--| do you actually need it?

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trains") '<-- reference your working worksheet
'        dec = .Range("L1") '<-- what's this for? in any case take it out of for loops since its value doesn't depend on current loop variables
        For Each objCell In .Range("L3:L100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through L3:L100 range not blank cells only
            If TrySetWorksheet(objCell.Value, "Trains", SH) Then '<--|Try to set the wanted worksheet in the wanted workbook: if successful it'd retrun 'True' and leave you with 'SH' variable set to the wanted worksheet
                shtDict(SH.Parent.Name) = shtDict(SH.Parent.Name) + 1
                Set rFndCell = SH.Range("C3:C1100").Find(objCell.Offset(, 2).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole) '<--| specify at least 'LookIn' and 'LookAt' parameters
                If Not rFndCell Is Nothing Then rFndCell.Offset(, 10).Resize(, 6).Value = objCell.Offset(, 3).Resize(, 6).Value
            End If
        Next objCell
    End With
    For Each key In shtDict.Keys '<--|loop through opened workbooks dictionary keys
        Workbooks(key).Close True '<--| close workbook whose name corresponds to current dictionary key
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function TrySetWorksheet(fileName As String, shtname As String, sht As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Set sht = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = Workbooks(Right(fileName, Len(fileName) - InStrRev(fileName, "\"))).Worksheets(shtname) '<--| try looking for an already open workbook with wanted name and wanted sheet
    If sht Is Nothing Then Set sht = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName).Worksheets(shtname) '<--| if not found then try opening the wanted workbook and set the wanted sheet in it
    TrySetWorksheet = Not sht Is Nothing '<--| set the return value to the final result of attempts at locating the wanted sheet
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a run in the morning

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider that in order to use `Dictionary` object you must add proper reference to your project: 1) in your VBA IDE select Tools-References 2) scroll the list box down to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" entry and tick the check box beside it 3) click "OK" button and you're done

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I didn't manage to get it to let me dim the dictionary - but I've got it mostly sorted now down a different path